# Find texts that contains quotation marks by xpath in Selenium

Tags: selenium, xpath, findelement

I just got an error in Selenium(Java):

> Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression
>   //*[contains(.,'The field SomeField must be a string or array type
>   with a maximum length of '60'.')]

Apparently, there are two `'` which broke the expression. So I changed the code from

```
WebElement elem = findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(.,'" + arg + "')]"));
```

to

```
WebElement elem = findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(.,'" + arg.toString().replace("'", "\'") + "')]"));
WebElement elem = findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(.,'" + arg.toString().replace("'", "\\'") + "')]"));
WebElement elem = findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(.,'" + arg.toString().replace("'", "\\\'") + "')]"));
```

None of them worked. Now I temporarily work it out by doing this:

```
WebElement elem = findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(.,\"" + arg + "\"')]"));
```

But the bug will come back if the arg contains `"` in it.

Anyone knows how to do that? Thanks for your help.

Comment: As the error shows... how long is `arg` if it's a long string you can reduce it as long as it's unique.

Comment: It varies case by case. I tried to shorten it to remove ', but it could be dangerous since there might be similar text on the same page. So it's better that I try the whole string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `String.format` to build your xpath the following ways:

```
WebElement elem = findElement(By.xpath(String.format("//*[contains(.,\"%s\")]", arg)));
```

For further information about String.format take a look at it's [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format(java.util.Locale,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...)).
The format arguments can be found [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax).

---

### arg can only contain `'`

```
WebElement elem = findElement(By.xpath(String.format("//*[contains(.,\"%s\")]", arg)));
```

### arg can only contain `"`

```
WebElement elem = findElement(By.xpath(String.format("//*[contains(.,'%s')]", arg)));
```

### arg can contain both `'` and `"`

Escape all `"` in arg with `arg.replace("\"", "&quot;");` and build your Xpath like

```
WebElement elem = findElement(By.xpath(String.format("//*[contains(.,\"%s\")]", arg)));
```

Comment: Thanks but it did not work for me. Now I'm using             WebElement elem = findElement(By.xpath(String.format("//*[contains(.,'%s')]", arg)));
and get error: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression //*[contains(.,'The field SomeField must be a string or array type with a maximum length of '60'.')] because of .... Just the same as that of the very beginning.

Comment: @cheny I updated my answer. Can you try it again? Replaced `'` with `\"`.

Comment: Yes that works. But what if there is "(rather than ') in arg?

Comment: @cheny Updated my answer.

Comment: nice fix `arg.replace("\"", "&quot;")`!!! as per OP's question `String.format()` is the way to go!

Comment: Hi guys I was busy on something else and just be back. Now I'm using             WebElement elem = findElement(By.xpath(String.format("//*[contains(.,\"%s\")]", arg.toString().replace("\"", "&quot;"))));
and get: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[contains(.,"&quot;name&quot;")]"}. Did I missed something?

Comment: Can you share the HTML or URL?