# Selenium Webdriver find element by Xpath problem with String quotation marks

Tags: c#, string, selenium, selenium-webdriver, quotation-marks

Here my code:

`var loginButton = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id="login - view"]/form/div[3]/button"));`

I saw already this post: [Find texts that contains quotation marks by xpath in Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59287319/find-texts-that-contains-quotation-marks-by-xpath-in-selenium)

but it doesn't help me

the quotation marks are The problem

Comment: do you have the full html? there is probably a better xpath for that then using div[3]. Those are extremely brittle.

Comment: yes here is the Button `<button type="submit" aria-label="Login button" class="btn btn-large p-x-2 btn-inverse" disabled="">Log In</button>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this use single quote to put id value in a string.

```
var loginButton = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='login - view']/form/div[3]/button"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Is the id property value correct? It has some spaces before and after "-"

Comment: Yes I copied directly the Xpath

Answer (score 0):

based on what you added here:

```
<button type="submit" aria-label="Login button" class="btn btn-large p-x-2 btn-inverse" disabled="">Log In</button>
```

This disabled attribute is causing issues because it makes the element, you guessed it, disabled! see - https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_disabled.asp

If you remove that so it looks like this:

```
<button type="submit" aria-label="Login button" class="btn btn-large p-x-2 btn-inverse">Log In</button>
```

then you could use the below and it will work fine.

```
//button[text()='Log In']
```

Is there another login button that is not disabled?

Comment: I know the Button is disabled but this is not the question, I have problem with the XPath string

Comment: Try a contains. //*[contains(text(), 'login - view')]

Comment: I tried already but this changes the xpath, and then he isn't valid anymore